# Unexplainable CS0102: on property setter

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I have a code snippet that translates JSON to C# code using `System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync<T>` in `System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.7.0 in ASP.net`. For this to work I (think I) need to have a few classes intermittently defined while parsing the content. I don't get to choose the names in the json file, they need to map to a class and one of the classes have properties that look like the example class below. This won't compile in `msbuild 16.5.0.12403`:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string set_id { get; set; }
}
```

This class gives me the following error:

**Class1.cs(3,29): error CS0102: The type 'Class1' already contains a definition for 'set_id'.**

My own solution to this was to rename set_id to Set_id and then it both compiled and the data was imported but what's going on here?

Comment: Side note: there obviously is no need for property names to match names in JSON - all serializers let you map JSON to whatever names you like... But that is totally unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any property the C# compiler automatically generates a `get_<Property>` and a `set_<Property>` method (if you have defined a setter) when you compile your code. Properties in C# are just syntactic sugar and are mapped onto methods.

You can see these automatically generated methods in the Intermediate Language (IL) code of your assembly. In fact, the compiler will also generate a backing field called `<Property>k_BackingField`. Usually you won't come accross this, unless you deal with reflection or IL code itself.

Since you have a property called `id`, the compiler will generate a `get_id` and a `set_id` method for you and this confilicts with your second property `set_id`, because this symbol is already defined.

Comment: Yes that's it, thanks for clarifying! (Searched but could not find that same older question prior to posting)